# Deploying node20 AWS Lambda function through Serverless.com sets module import to ESM

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

We are using Serverless.com to deploy Lambda functions to AWS and have started upgrading some older functions to node20.

```yaml
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs20.x

functions:
  routeInvoice:
    handler: src/functions/routeInvoice/routeInvoice.handler
```

There is a file as `src/functions/routeInvoice/routeInvoice.js` which has the exported function:

```js
const handler = async (event, context) => {
  console.log('event:', JSON.stringify(event), JSON.stringify(context));

  try {
    return await routeInvoice(event);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('routeInvoice handler error:', err);
    throw err;
  }
};

module.exports = { handler };
```

After deploy though we get the error:

```
{
    "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
    "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'handler'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
    "stack": [
        "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'handler'",
        "Require stack:",
        "- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
        "    at _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1087:17)",
        "    at async UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1119:21)",
        "    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1282:23)",
        "    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1288:1"
    ]
}
```

`package.json` don't have any `type` attribute, and according to AWS documentation the file extension `.js` should be treated as Common JS and not ESM...

Executing the function locally using `sls invoke local -f routeInvoice...` works fine!

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

We have both Java Lambda's and Node.js Lambdas in the same Serverless.yml and the packaging seems to work differently between SLS v2 and now v3.

I moved the `package: artifact` to the Java functions instead so the Java code didn't end up in the Node.js Lambda ZIP and now it is working fine!

Apparently AWS gets confused when there is Java code in a Node.js Lambda and then seems to default to ESM...